# Are there flies that can spray their eggs while flying?

Tags: species-identification, infectious-diseases

While I was reading a few articles about parasitic infections caused by flies, to be specific *Myiasis*, I read something saying that some flies can spray their eggs when they are flying around their target instead of having to stay on it and lay the eggs there.

Is this true? What's the name of these kind of flies?

PS1: I include part of the source translated to English:

> Dr. A. Khazani ,entomologist &  an expert in charge of the vector control program of Isfahan province, emphasized that environment hygiene is particularly important in preventing people from contracting myiasis, added: S*ome flies spray their eggs while flying*, which may get inside the ears, nose, and eyes. and... penetrate and cause disease

Source: IMNA, A Metropoitan News Agency, June 8th, 2019

Names of the species were not mentioned in the source article.

Comment: Welcome Merlot. "Almost"? Personally I can almost afford a new car. I'm not sure if such a creature exists, but if you were to add the results of your investigations to the body of the question (even if inconclusive) that would definitely improve the question. I find that [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/) is handy for translating quoted, why not give it a try.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I translated that part of the source & put it in here.